# Download data with topological classification

Tags: pymatgen

In the materials project database, In the electronic structure part of compounds, there is a tag for “Topological Classification”. I am wondering if this data can be added to the properties of the query?

```
properties = ["pretty_formula", "cif", "material_id"]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.